# Python script not ending after closing TKinter GUI

Tags: python, sockets, tkinter

Good morning,

I am trying to make a Python-Excel (via VBA) communication to display messages during VBA run time using a python TKinter GUI.

The code can exit by 2 options, 1.- Identify a "STOP" message sent from VBA or, 2.- Have received no message in a certain timeout.

I am having problems with exiting gratefully in either of the 2 options. TKinter sometimes closes, but python code is left hanging in the CMD, or in Visual Studio IDE command line, so that I don't get prompted for a next command, just keeps living inside the script forever, which is by no means the intended functionality. Code below.

```
import tkinter as tk
import socket
import threading
import sys
import time
from queue import Queue

g_strSERVER = "127.0.0.1"
g_lPORT = int(sys.argv[1])
g_lTIMEOUT = 2 # As low for testing purposes only

def F_WND_CenterWindow(oWindow, lTargetWidth, lTargetHeight):
    lScreenWidth = oWindow.winfo_screenwidth()
    lScreenHeight = oWindow.winfo_screenheight()

    x = (lScreenWidth - lTargetWidth) // 2
    y = (lScreenHeight - lTargetHeight) // 2

    oWindow.geometry(f"{lTargetWidth}x{lTargetHeight}+{x}+{y}")

class clsMessageWindow:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = tk.Tk()
        self.root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.quit_me)
        self.root.title("Log display")
        print("setting log display")

        # Set the window size (change these values as needed)
        lTargetWindowWidth = 640
        lTargetWindowHeight = 380

        # Center the window on the screen and keep it above all windows
        F_WND_CenterWindow(self.root, lTargetWidth=lTargetWindowWidth, lTargetHeight=lTargetWindowHeight)
        self.root.wm_attributes("-topmost",1)
        
        self.text_widget = tk.Text(self.root)
        self.text_widget.pack()

        self.queue = Queue()
        self.socket_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_socket_server)
        self.stop_flag = threading.Event()  # Event to signal the thread to stop
        self.socket_thread.start()
        print("all setup with log display")
        self.last_message_received_at = time.time()

    def start_socket_server(self):
        server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        server_socket.bind((g_strSERVER,g_lPORT))
        server_socket.listen(1)
        print(f"Server started listening {g_strSERVER}:{g_lPORT}")

        while not self.stop_flag.is_set():  # Check the stop flag
            try:
                oClientSocket, _ = server_socket.accept()
                strMessageData = oClientSocket.recv(1024).decode("utf-8")
                arrSplitMessage = strMessageData.split('\n')
                strMessage = arrSplitMessage[-1]
                print(f"Received message: {strMessage}")

                if strMessage == "STOP":
                    print("Received STOP")
                    self.stop_flag.set()  # Set the stop flag to exit the loop
                else:
                    print(f"Adding message to queue: {strMessage}")
                    self.queue.put(strMessage)
                oClientSocket.close()
            except Exception as e:
                print(f"Error: {e}")

        # Close the server socket when done
        server_socket.close()

    def process_queue(self):
        while not self.queue.empty():
            strMessage = self.queue.get()
            self.add_message(strMessage)
            self.last_message_received_at = time.time()

        print(f"Checking if flag is set: {self.stop_flag.is_set()}")
        if not self.stop_flag.is_set():
            # Check the queue periodically if the stop flag is not set
            self.root.after(100, self.process_queue)
            current_time = time.time()
            print("Elapsed time: ", current_time - self.last_message_received_at)
            if current_time - self.last_message_received_at > g_lTIMEOUT:
                self.stop_flag.set()
                print("Over Timeout")
                self.quit_me()
        else:
            # Exit the mainloop gracefully if the stop flag is set
            self.quit_me()

    def quit_me(self):
        print("Exiting TKinter gratefully")
        self.root.quit()
        self.root.destroy()

    def add_message(self, strMessage):
        if len(strMessage) > 0:
            self.text_widget.insert(tk.END, strMessage + "\n")
            # Scroll to the end to show the message
            self.text_widget.see(tk.END)

    def run(self):
        self.process_queue()
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    message_window = clsMessageWindow()
    message_window.run()
```

Thanks

Comment: Perhaps the socket documentation note

 "
Note

close() releases the resource associated with a connection but does not necessarily close the connection immediately. If you want to close the connection in a timely fashion, call shutdown() before close(). 
"
would help.

Comment: Alternatively you could use use the socket in a with block, i.e. with  socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM) as server_socket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `socket_thread` is still working when you try to exit, which is causing the hang.

You can use a so-called daemonic thread which will be killed when your application exits. Setting this up should be as simple as:

```
self.socket_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.start_socket_server, daemon=True)
```

Comment: That did the trick, thank you so much! I tried upvoting, but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Comment: No worries! Happy to help - good luck to ya